# Copy from a dynamic range using a loop and pasting to a dynamic range using a loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to write an If statement to copy an entire row; if a cell within a specific column contains an identifier, then paste the entire row into the worksheet (worksheet's name is equal to identifier) on the next available empty row, else search the next row for the identifier.

I have about 40 unique identifiers that need their rows to go into 40 unique worksheets. Ideally, I'd like to create a single loop that looks at a matrix of identifiers and the respectable worksheets that the rows (with those identifiers) should be pasted.

My code:

```
Worksheets("XL Detail").Activate
Dim IR As Worksheet, r As Long
Set IR = Worksheets("XL Detail")
Dim AS1 As Worksheet, a1 As Long
Set AS1 = Worksheets("12102")
mRow = AS1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
nRow = mRow + 1
For r = 2 To IR.Range("a1048576").End(xlUp).Row Step 1
   If IR.Range("C" & r).Value = "12102" Then IR.Range("C" & r).EntireRow.Copy
    AS1.Cells(nRow, 1).PasteSpecial
    nRow = nRow + 1
    Next r
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Tested

This will loop through your sheets and then loop through `Column C` on your sheet `XL Detail` grabbing all rows that have a value equal to the current sheets name

```
Option Explicit

Sub Master_Loop()

Dim ms As Worksheet: Set ms = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("XL Detail")
Dim LR As Long, ws As Worksheet, xCell As Range, CopyMe As Range
Dim x As Long

LR = ms.Range("C" & ms.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each ws In Worksheets

        If ws.Name <> ms.Name Then
            For Each xCell In ms.Range("C2:C" & LR)
                If xCell = ws.Name Then
                    If Not CopyMe Is Nothing Then
                        Set CopyMe = Union(CopyMe, xCell)
                    Else
                        Set CopyMe = xCell
                    End If
                End If
            Next xCell
        End If

        If Not CopyMe Is Nothing Then
            x = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            CopyMe.EntireRow.Copy ws.Range("A" & x)
            Set CopyMe = Nothing
        End If

    Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. As I F8 through the loop, nothing is actually being pasted in its respected worksheets. I'm also receiving an error if I F5 that says "You can't paste this here because the Copy area and paste area aren't the same size. Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size, and try pasting again." Do you know what I have to add to include pasting the rows and mitigating the error message?

Comment: Thanks again. I'm blown away by how fast this is, however I'm experiencing some issues. There is data from the XL Details ws being pasted in every ws, regardless of the ws name-- including the XL Details ws itself. The data is being duplicated in that ws. The only ws that looks to have the proper data is the very first ws, the remainder of the worksheets are inaccurate.

Comment: OH. Yes. One second

Comment: JESUS CRISTO! Please let me know if you offer lessons... this is truly unbelievable!  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will work too. (It might be a bit faster than looping through each row.)

If you try it and get too many message boxes (due to non-existent sheets), maybe just put some other logic in the `Else` branch of the `If` statement.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CopyPasteToCorrespondingSheets()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XL Detail")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .Cells.AutoFilter ' Do this here before lastRow

        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        Dim rangeContainingIdentifiers As Range
        Set rangeContainingIdentifiers = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)
    End With

    Dim uniqueIdentifers As Collection
    Set uniqueIdentifers = UniqueValuesInRange(rangeContainingIdentifiers)

    Dim uniqueSheetName As Variant
    Dim sheetToPasteTo As Worksheet

    ' Not sure if there is a better way to include the row immediately above the first row of a particular range
    With rangeContainingIdentifiers.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(1 + rangeContainingIdentifiers.Rows.Count, 1)
        For Each uniqueSheetName In uniqueIdentifers
            On Error Resume Next
            Set sheetToPasteTo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(uniqueSheetName)
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not (sheetToPasteTo Is Nothing) Then
                lastRow = sheetToPasteTo.Cells(sheetToPasteTo.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=uniqueSheetName
                rangeContainingIdentifiers.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
                sheetToPasteTo.Cells(lastRow + 1, "C").EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

                Set sheetToPasteTo = Nothing
            Else
                MsgBox ("No sheet named '" & uniqueSheetName & "' was found. Code will continue running (for rest of unique identifiers).")
            End If
        Next uniqueSheetName

        .AutoFilter
    End With

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub

Private Function UniqueValuesInRange(ByRef rangeToCheck As Range, Optional rowsToSkip As Long = 0) As Collection
    Dim inputArray() As Variant
    inputArray = rangeToCheck.Value2

    Dim outputCollection As Collection ' Will not differentiate between "10" and 10
    Set outputCollection = New Collection

    Dim rowIndex As Long
    Dim collectionKey As String

    For rowIndex = (LBound(inputArray, 1) + rowsToSkip) To UBound(inputArray, 1)
        collectionKey = CStr(inputArray(rowIndex, 1))

        ' Only look at first column.
        On Error Resume Next
        outputCollection.Add Item:=collectionKey, Key:=collectionKey
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next rowIndex

    Set UniqueValuesInRange = outputCollection
End Function
```

Comment: Hey-- thank you for this! This works really well, with the exception that it doesn't paste the values in the next available row on each of the respected worksheets. Do you know how I can thread that in?

Comment: @Drew10005, seems like you've got a working/accepted solution. For what it's worth, I think I was missing a `+1` on this line `sheetToPasteTo.Cells(lastRow, "C").EntireRow.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` and have now amended my code. Other than that, I think it should work as intended (I tested it on some dummy data on my end just now).